# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 6)

Tags: json, python-requests

Following a YouTube video tutorial. The guy did the exact same thing but he didn't encounter any error. Whats wrong with my code?

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://ap.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow')

print(response.json())
```

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 6)

Comment: Same issue here, did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should print the response to view what is the result before execute get the JSON maybe the response is null

```py
print(response)

if response:
    # Do something

if not response:
    # Do something
```

Comment: result is 200 OK

Comment: Try to remove the line `import json` and run it again @HarshalTijare